# How to change equal (=) to not equal to (<>) in postgres using Go

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, go

I have two sql querys that are very similar. The only difference is that in one of the WHERE clauses I am using equal to (=) instead of not equal to (<>). Is there a way to modify the query programmatically in an elegant way? I am looking for something like this:

```
func getEvents(name string, exclude bool) {
    q := `SELECT * FROM events WHERE name`
    if exclude {
        q = q + " <> "
    } else {
        q = q + " = "
    }
    q = q + "$1"

    result, err := DBQuery(q, name)
    ...
}
```

Comment: "I am looking for something like this" What is wrong with "this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant way would be to create a type and constants for the operators:

```
type Op string

const (
    OpEqual       Op = "="
    OpNotEqual    Op = "<>"
    OpLessThan    Op = "<"
    OpGreaterThan Op = ">"
    // ... any other ops you need
)
```

And then building the query string is a simple string concatenation:

```
q := "SELECT * FROM events WHERE name" + op + "$1"
```

Or you may use [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf):

```
q := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM events WHERE name %s $1", op)
```

Of course change signature of `getEvents()` to:

```
func getEvents(name string, op Op)
```

And calling `getEvents()` is now even nicer:

```
getEvents("error", OpEqual)
getEvents("error", OpNotEqual)
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sq1_EglEeK8).

Comment: the constants are missing their type